# Strange behaviour NgOptions

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, model-binding, ng-options

Working with AngularJS version v1.2.9.
I have page with two controllers. All works fine, except a select using ng-options, but only in IE. Chrome works fine.
Can't post the entire code since it's 1500loc.

Here the HTML snippet:

```
<div class="auswahlDialog ms-dlgContent">
    <div class="ms-dlgBorder">
        <div class="ms-dlgTitle">
            <span class="ms-dlgTitleBtns" ng-click="closeUploadDocumentDialog()">
                <span style="padding: 8px; height: 16px; width: 16px; display: inline-block;">
                    <span class="s4-clust">
                        <img src="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png?rev=23" alt="Dialogfeld schließen" class="ms-dlgCloseBtnImg" />
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <h2 class="ms-webpart-titleText">Kunde auswählen</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="ms-dlgFrameContainer" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="neueAkte">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle">Dokumentart:</td>
                            <td>
                                <select ng-model="betriebsaktart" ng-options="b.id as b.title for b in betriebsaktarten" style="background-color: #fff;"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                                <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="return false;" ng-click="saveItem(betriebsaktart)" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth">
                                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" ng-click="closeDialog()" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data comes from SharePoint but it's an array of very simple objects:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById("14995573-DAA6-4334-AE6B-D79CB98EC92C"); //Betriebsaktarten
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Title"/></OrderBy></Query></View>');
    var items = list.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 

        $scope.betriebsaktarten = items.get_data().map(function(item){
            return {
                id: item.get_id(),
                title: item.get_item('Title'),
            }
        });
        $scope.$digest();

    }, function(request, error) { 
        $scope.$digest();
        showError(error);
    })
}, 'SP.js')
```

For non SharePoint developers: `$scope.$digest();` must be called since `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` is async.

In Chrome it works as expected.
 
In IE10/IE11 data gets loaded, when an option is selected for the first time the UI shows the first one. When an(other) option is selected again, the UI shows the correct one. Note: When I click 'Save' the passed value is always the right one, even if the UI shows the wrong one.
It is only a visual problem.
There are no errors in the console.
Another Note: the HTML snippet is loaded using ng-include. I also tryied to insert the html code into the page w/o using ng-include, problem on IE persists.

Any Hints?

Comment: Have you tried using <option ng-repeat="b.id as b.title for b in betriebsaktarten"></option> ? If I remember correctly there were a lot of pain coming from ng-options that could be avoided with a simple ng-repeat.

Comment: ...when I started using angularJS I read that using ng-repeat on options should be avoided due to the binding.

Comment: To fix such problems, you first need to isolate it -- create simple plunk with one select and $timeout instead of $http call.

Comment: I don't use `$http`

Comment: what about ui-select then ? https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/